# How do you make links in grafana table panel from a cell relative, so they can suit other grafana servers

Tags: hyperlink, grafana

How to make the link connected to a table panel cell pointing to a dashboard in the same grafana server?
The need is to avoid needing to edit the link after importing from a different grafana server so it's deployable anywhere.

I have a link like the following:

http://200.25.25.169:3000/d/CT3AnUrZk/dashboard1?orgId=1&var-network_name=All&var-vm_name=$__cell

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to omit the scheme (http protocol) and host part from the url so the link that works looks like this:

/d/CT3AnUrZk/dashboard1?orgId=1&&var-network_name=All&var-vm_name=$__cell